# collectd, java plugin: Cannot find the API class org.collectd.api.Collectd

Tags: java, collectd

I'm trying to run java plugin GenericJMX on collectd but I'm stuck on collectd API.

I got this message: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/collectd/api/Collectd has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 54.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

On my system there is installed java version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16 LTS, but this log is telling me that I only recognize versions up to 52.0, which should be version 8.

This is some internal JRE of collectd?

Comment: TL;DR you are using old JRE. Just update it (mentioned version code 54 should correspond to java 10, but you have java 8 installed).

Comment: As I mentioned I don't know where is used old java. Java package installed on this server ( Debian Stretch) is Java 11